# Can Windows 7 restore files from NTBackup archives that were created under Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, ntbackup

We will be replacing all Windows XP Pro installations with Windows 7 Pro.

Under Windows XP, backups were done using NTBackup.

We will switch to the built-in backup in Windows 7. Will we be able to restore files from NTBackup archives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect that the tool available here will also work on Windows 7, though I haven't tried it (and don't have my Windows 7 machine handy right now, unfortunately...)

[Windows NT Backup - Restore Utility](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7da725e2-8b69-4c65-afa3-2a53107d54a7&displaylang=en) - Utility for restoring backups made on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 to computers running Windows Vista and Microsoft® Windows Server® 2008.